# Serde struct version check

Tags: rust, serde

I want to add a simple version scheme + check to my struct:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Versioned {
    version: u32,
    other_field: String,
}

impl Versioned {
    const FORMAT_VERSION: u32 = 42;
}
```

The idea is rather simple: the `version` field is deserialized (0 if not present*), and an error is thrown if it does not equal `FORMAT_VERSION`. Then, the rest of the struct is processed. The order here is important: otherwise, the deserialization error might not be correct (you might get something like "missing field `new_field`" instead of "version too old").

I've tried a few ideas with wrapper types and custom deserializers, but none of them provided a good user experience. My best so far:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Payload {
    some_field: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "version")]
enum Versioned {
    #[serde(rename = "0")]
    Inner(Payload),
}
```

It uses an enum wrapper for the version check, and two `From` implementations for easy type conversion. The downsides are:

- No default value for the field* (= not backwards compatible with unversioned data)
- Bad error message on old version ("Error: unknown variant `42`, expected `0` at line 2 column 17" instead of something like "invalid version")

---

* **Notice:** the backwards compatibility requirement makes things significantly more difficult. So remember folks, always add a `version` field to all your data right away!

Comment: @JeroenVervaeke Since 90% of my use cases are JSON serialization that's be fine, although I'd prefer a more generic solution. (Depending on self-describing data formats is fine though)

Comment: Do you have the requirement to have version field in struct? Enums are actually backwards compatible if you don't change existing variants, only add new variants to them when you change the struct. Later when old versions are replaced, you can even remove the old variants.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all the other answers for the inspiration! See also https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1799 and https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/912#issuecomment-981657911 for more details on the untagged enum trick I'm using.

Basically, two steps are needed to improve the code from the question as desired:

1. Add a `#[serde(other)] Unsupported` variant to the versioned enum
2. Wrap the enum in another, untagged enum that handles the default version (called `Legacy`)

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Data {
    field: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "version")]
pub enum VersionChecked {
    #[serde(rename = "0")]
    V0(Data),
    #[serde(other)]
    Unsupported,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
pub enum DefaultVersion {
    Versioned(VersionChecked),
    Legacy(Data),
    // Optional, if you want to "catch" the serde error
    // Invalid(serde_json::Value),
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(serde_json::from_str::<DefaultVersion>(r#"{ "version": 0, "field": "Somestring" }"#).unwrap());
    dbg!(serde_json::from_str::<DefaultVersion>(r#"{ "field": "Somestring" }"#).unwrap());
    dbg!(serde_json::from_str::<DefaultVersion>(r#"{ "blablah": "blablah" }"#));
    dbg!(serde_json::from_str::<DefaultVersion>(r#"{ "version": 42, "foo": "bar" }"#));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ad6bbf931733ab67a46d805a5ac697e)

Some improvements on the usage can still be made. I'm thinking of `TryFrom<DefaultVersion> for Data` for the one direction, and some `serialize_as` for the other one. But for now it will do.

Answer (score 1):

My first approach was to try and build a custom deserializer which first deserializes into a new struct (`VersionedModel` which derives `Deserialize`) with only the `version` field. This doesn't work since `VersionedModel::deserialize(deserializer)` consumes the deserializer so you're unable to deserialize any other data.

My second approach would be using one of the methods on `Deserializer<'de>`, however, all methods consume the deserializer, so you wouldn't be able to first read the version and then the other fields.

The third (and most naive approach, not so clean but it works) would be to to implement your deserialize in 2 steps like this:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Versioned {
    version: u32,
    other_field: String,
}

impl Versioned {
    const FORMAT_VERSION: u32 = 42;
}

#[derive(Debug, Error)]
pub enum DeserializeError {
    #[error("Version field is missing")]
    VersionIsMissing,
    #[error("Invalid version, got: {actual:}, expected: {expected:}")]
    InvalidVersion { actual: u32, expected: u32 },
    #[error(transparent)]
    DeserializeError(#[from] serde_json::Error),
}

fn deserialize_model(value: &str) -> Result<Versioned, DeserializeError> {
    #[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
    struct VersionOnly {
        version: u32,
    }

    let VersionOnly { version } =
        serde_json::from_str(&value).map_err(|_| DeserializeError::VersionIsMissing)?;

    if version == Versioned::FORMAT_VERSION {
        Ok(serde_json::from_str(&value)?)
    } else {
        Err(DeserializeError::InvalidVersion {
            actual: version,
            expected: Versioned::FORMAT_VERSION,
        })
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dc9d4cd7119d5ded4e5c1ff9fd85da1c)

Last approach: write your own serializer, write your own visitors (basically copy paste all generated macro code and add some changes). I would **not** recommend this approach since it's very error prone and probably not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve both your points by writing a custom deserialization function for the `version` field. You make it optional by putting `#[serde(default)]` on the field.
The custom deserialization function can have any logic you want for checking the version number and produce your desired error message.

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Versioned {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "ensure_version", default)]
    version: u32,
    other_field: String,
}

impl Versioned {
    const FORMAT_VERSION: u32 = 42;
}

fn ensure_version<'de, D: Deserializer<'de>>(d: D) -> Result<u32, D::Error> {
    let version = u32::deserialize(d)?;
    if version != Versioned::FORMAT_VERSION {
        return Err(D::Error::custom("Version mismatch for Versioned"));
    }
    Ok(version)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=26fb94ea98b6e9a8b2c36d8390b1aa0a)

Comment: This would be the way to go if OP would drop this requirement: "an error is thrown if it does not equal FORMAT_VERSION. _Then_, the rest of the struct is processed.". Here we have no guarantee version will be validated before other_field.

Comment: if the `version` field comes first in the serialized form it will also be processed first. The order between the fields could be a problem, for example if you change the type of a field. But you will never get a missing field error with the above code, since the field is always processed before the `Versioned` checks for missing fields.

If you want the `version` field to be always processed before anything else, you need to use something like the externally tagged enum. The "solution" with the adjacently tagged enum from OP does not achieve that.

Comment: I'd like to see a version that uses the untagged enum trick from my answer to ensure correct serialization. Something like `#[serde(flatten)] payload: MaybePayload` and then `#[serde(untagged)] enum MaybePayload { Payload(Payload), Invalid(serde_json::Value)}`. Then, use some type conversion method to convert the error depending on the `version` value.